# Javascript - function with objects

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm trying to write a function, but it's doing the opposite of what I'd like.

Write a function that determines whether a user 
is old and tall enough to ride a roller coaster. The 
function should take an object as a parameter. If 
the object's age property is greater than or equal to 
7 and the height property is greater than or equal to 
42, return true. Otherwise, return false

```js
 const rollerCoaster = (object) => {
  if (object.age >= 7 && object.height >= 42) {
      return true
  } else {
      return false
  }
}

console.log(rollerCoaster(55, 55));
```

This is returning false, we want it to return true. What am I missing?

Comment: Your call to the function is passing two number parameters instead of one object. Try `console.log(rollerCoaster({age: 55, height: 55}))`

Comment: yup, you're right, thanks for that

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in two numbers as the parameters, rather than an object. The function is not working because referencing the number as an object returns undefined or null, therefore making the function return false.